# Getting list of empty objects for API calls in Firebase

Tags: firebase, http, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am building a firebase app that calculates the commute times between "from" and "to" addresses that are stored in my Realtime Database. I want to call an API to calculate each commute and return those commute times once all have been calculated. I am using `Promise.all` for the first time to frame this behavior. However, in the end, I am only getting empty objects for the result of my calls. Any tips?

```
exports.updateCommutes = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const ref = admin.database().ref('/users/test_user/commutes');

  return ref.once('value').then((snapshot)=>{

    var urls = [];

    const testURl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?key=XXXX&origins=Boston,MA&destinations=Cambridge,MA'; // I'm using a test API call for now


    return Promise.all([fetch(testURl),fetch(testURl)])
    .then((responses)=>{
      return responses.map((res)=>res.json())
    })
    .then((data)=>{
      console.log(data);// this prints out: [ Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> } ]
      return response.send(data);
    })


  })
  .catch((error)=>console.log("error$"+error))
});
```

My database looks like this:

```
icommute-firebase
-   users
-   -   test_user
-   -   -   commutes
-   -   -   -   M26JimVJ3P_nEvm1L6n
-   -   -   -   -   from: Boston,MA
-   -   -   -   -   to: Cambridge,MA
-   -   -   -   M26Joyu-rLGomY_oElm
-   -   -   -   M26JtYyvGK_fCx0FE-Q
-   -   -   -   M26Qhuc-gebRppy320c
```

With Postman on a GET request to http://localhost:5001/icommute-firebase/us-central1/updateCommutes, results in:

```
[
    {},
    {}
]
```

when I am expecting:

```
[
{
   "destination_addresses": [
      "Cambridge, MA, USA"
   ],
   "origin_addresses": [
      "Boston, MA, USA"
   ],
   "rows": [
      {
         "elements": [
            {
               "distance": {
                  "text": "4.9 km",
                  "value": 4925
               },
               "duration": {
                  "text": "16 mins",
                  "value": 978
               },
               "status": "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status": "OK"
},
{
   "destination_addresses": [
      "Cambridge, MA, USA"
   ],
   "origin_addresses": [
      "Boston, MA, USA"
   ],
   "rows": [
      {
         "elements": [
            {
               "distance": {
                  "text": "4.9 km",
                  "value": 4925
               },
               "duration": {
                  "text": "16 mins",
                  "value": 978
               },
               "status": "OK"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status": "OK"
}
]
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the relevant contents of your database, as well as describe what you think the function should return to the client.

Comment: Done! Any thoughts now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res.json()` also returns a Promise. So you need to handle it too. See the example below:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const testURl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1'
return Promise.all([fetch(testURl),fetch(testURl)])
    .then((responses)=>{
      // res.json() returns a Promise.
      // We need to wrap them again in Promise.all()
      return Promise.all(responses.map((res)=>res.json()));
    })
    .then((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
    });
```

This logs the expected output:

```
[ { userId: 1,
    id: 1,
    title: 'delectus aut autem',
    completed: false },
  { userId: 1,
    id: 1,
    title: 'delectus aut autem',
    completed: false } ]
```

Comment: Wow, I overlooked that. Thank you so much!